# Running Ubuntu in Virtual Box-Not enough RAM

Tags: virtualbox, ram

I downloaded virtual box with plans to run Ubuntu in it. I downloaded the most recent version and when I got into VirtualBox it said I did not have enough RAM. My pc has 8GB total. Is there a version that requires less RAM to run?

Comment: How much RAM did you try to allocate? How much RAM is the host using?

Comment: 8G RAM is enough to run VB, but the RAM for the guest OS's has to be somewhere in 1024-2048 range, depending on how much free RAM the host has available, and also how many other guest OS's you have running at the same time. Also, set your guest OS settings for 2 processors.

Comment: Did you get this error while installing VirtualBox or while installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you mean the VM didn't have enough RAM. I doubt that even the most bling crazed Ubuntu devs have loaded down the flagship product to the point it can't run in 8 GiB. Presuming that, just open VirtualBox and create a new VM. Pay attention to the dialogues. At one point you are asked how much RAM to give it. Give it more until it works. I would think 2 GiB should be sufficient, but try and err and try again until it works.

Added by edit: Heynnema's comment wasn't there when I started. I type slow. It looks like an answer to me. He should get the credit.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

8G RAM is enough to run VB, but the RAM for the guest OS's has to be somewhere in 1024-2048 range, depending on how much free RAM the host has available, and also how many other guest OS's you have running at the same time. Also, set your guest OS settings for 2 processors.